# Как правильно реализовать цепочку rxjava в android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava

Я пытаюсь реализовать условия отсутствия интернета на мобильном устройстве. При этом должна происходить такая последовательность операций в цепочке:
1.Проверяем время последнего запроса
2.Делаем запрос на rest api
3.В случае удачи мы наполняем кэш и БД данными с сервера, в противном случае(он работает неверно) мы отлавливаем ошибку, берем данные из БД и наполняем ими `PublisherSubject`. Потом мы включаем связь и дергаем `Swipe fefresh` нашего фрагмента. Я пробовал методы `doOnError` `onErrorReturn` `onErrorResumeNext`. В каждом из них происходила такая интересная ситуация в коде: сначала дергается (1) потом (2) и потом, не могу понять почему (3), из-за чего данные приходят несколько раз, с каждым проходом увеличиваются на 1, как будто цепочка накапливает ошибки. Кто может с этим сталкивался и может помочь мне с этой проблемой? Буду очень благодарен

Так же в цепочке присутствует внешняя зависимость от Системного времени, что не хорошо, если по ней будут какие-то статьи на прочтение тоже буду признателен

```
override fun requestAllCountries(): Flowable<Any> {
        return getTimeSinceLastUpdate()
            .flatMap { isMoreThanMinute ->
                return@flatMap if (isMoreThanMinute) {
                    lastNetworkRequestTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    networkRepository.getCountryDate()
                        .doOnError {
       (3)        databaseRepository.getAllCountries().subscribe({countrySubject.onNext(it)}, {})
                        }
                        .flatMap {
                            it.forEach { item ->
                                databaseRepository.addLanguage(item.languages)
                            }
                        (1)  databaseRepository.addAllCountries(it)
                        (2)  cacheRepository.addAllCountries(it)
                        }
                } else {
                    cacheRepository.getAllCountries()
                }
            }
            .doOnNext {
                Log.e("HZ", "$it")
                countrySubject.onNext(it)
            }
            .map { Any() }
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `.doOnError` не отлавливает ошибку, а просто исполняется, если в цепочке была ошибка. Видимо при обращении к `cacheRepository.addAllCountries(it)` возникает ошибка, это и вызывает `doOnError`

Comment: " с каждым проходом увеличиваются на 1, как будто цепочка накапливает ошибки." вот это не совсем понятно, подробнее можете описать поведение?

Comment: Я извиняюсь может быть за глупый вопрос, я не так давно работаю с rxjava. Но может есть возможность заглушить цепочку, после того как она она встретила ошибку и выполнила еще 1 действие после нее? (Пытаемся достучаться на сервер, ловим ошибку и тут же берем данные из БД, прокидываем их в subject и глушимся)

Comment: Более подробно:   Выключили интернет на мобильном, попытались подключиться, не получилось, взяли данные из бд. Свайпаем экран в надежде, что интернет появился, допустим 4 раза. За это время, если все запросы идут в сеть, а не локально в кэш(он работает так как я и ожидал), то при включении интернета на мобильном и свайпе экрана мы идем на сервер, берем данные, потом заходим 1 раз в пункт 1, 1 раз в пункт 2 и 4 раза в пункт 3. Соответственно лайв дата, на выходе заполняет адаптер ресайклера 5 раз. А цепочка бегает туда сюда, так как после каждого пункта 3 у нас данные летят в лайв дату

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, у вас основная проблема - в подписывании на источник данных внутри другого источника данных. Что, конечно, можно решить управляя завершением подписки. Однако, лучше вообще избегать таких решений - подписки внутри источника.

Алгоритм проблемный у вас вот почему:

1. Выключили сеть.
2. Запустили запрос в сеть.
3. Подписались на изменения из БД. Оно у вас, видимо, не Single, а Flowable(или Observable). Т.е. выдаёт событие при изменениях в БД, дергая Subject.
4. После включения сети вы получаете данные с сервера.
5. Пришедшие данные записываете в БД, вызывая срабатывание ранее зарегистрированных подписок на эти изменения (см. п.3)

Простым (и очень сомнительным) решением будет заменить тип источника данных `databaseRepository.getAllCountries()` на Single. Так он сработает всего один раз и не будет реагировать на дальнейшие изменения в БД.

Правильным решением же было бы не создание внутренней подписки, но модификация имеющегося источника данных. Главное - уследить какие типы источников используются. Мне неизвестен ожидаемый принцип работы, так что предположу, что вам надо просто получить данные из кэша или сети (записав данные в БД и кэш). И не надо, чтобы источник данных продолжал жить своей сложной жизнью:

```
override fun requestAllCountries(): Completable {
    return getTimeSinceLastUpdate() // должен быть Single
        .flatMap { isMoreThanMinute ->
            if (isMoreThanMinute) {
                lastNetworkRequestTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                networkRepository.getCountryDate() // должен быть Single
                    .doOnSuccess {
                        it.forEach { item ->
                            databaseRepository.addLanguage(item.languages) // не должно быть Rx
                        }
                        databaseRepository.addAllCountries(it) // не должно быть Rx
                        cacheRepository.addAllCountries(it) // не должно быть Rx
                    }
                   .flatMap {
                        databaseRepository.getAllCountries() // должен быть Single
                    }
                    .onErrorResumeNext(
                        databaseRepository.getAllCountries() // должен быть Single
                    )
            } else {
                cacheRepository.getAllCountries() // должен быть Single
            }
        }
        .doOnSuccess {
            Log.e("HZ", "$it")
            countrySubject.onNext(it)
        }
        .ignoreElement()
}
```